# Python - Resolve objects on Image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I need to detect objects on image from simple game Chrome Dyno. I'm using Python and Selenium to start game, and load Canvas Image. Main taks, it's detect objects on this image and find Dyno and Dyno Barriers.

[image]

I'm using this code, to parse all objects on picture using OpenCV, `cv2` library.
Below this code (two main functions), which takes around 80 - 200 ms (based on barriers size) to recognize all objects.

`

```
# Finding only dino object based on Template.
# This might be optimized later with searching by contours

def find_dino__(self, cv2_image):
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(cv2_image.astype(np.uint8), self.dino_image, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
    _, _, _, dino_top_left = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
    dino_bottom_right = (dino_top_left[0] + self.dino_width, dino_top_left[1] + self.dino_height)
    return GenericGameObject(dino_top_left, dino_bottom_right)

# Find other Barrier Objects, based on position, and except
# that, which behind Dino location. Use Dino position.
def find_dino_barriers__(self, cv2_image, dino_object):
    img_fil = cv2.medianBlur(cv2.cvtColor(cv2_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), 13)
    img_th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img_fil, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_th, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    objects = []
    for i in range(len(contours)):
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[i])
        if y < Settings.DINO_WORKING_Y_AREA[0] \
                or y > Settings.DINO_WORKING_Y_AREA[1]:
            continue
        if x <= dino_object.top_right_point[0]\
                and y <= dino_object.top_right_point[1]:
            continue
        objects.append(GenericGameObject((x, y), (x + w, y + h)))

    return objects
```

`

My goal, it's **reduce this time**, as much as it possible, to make game playable for other scripts. BTW I inspired IAMDinosaur project, where using JS and Robot JS this task was done pretty well.

Comment: One simple step would be to use OpenCV with Cuda/OpenCL, if you've a GPU on your machine.

Comment: @Zindarod I openned for all suggestions, and might check this with OpenCL later. I even thinking about pausing game (throw activate/deactivate window) to save time during object recognition.

Comment: I was doing a similar project several months ago, playing the t rex bot using Pyautogui with the help of opencv. The program can score around 500 but then the slow process of screenshot technique causes the bot to death. Here is the repo if it help you somehow: https://github.com/arsho/t_rex_bot

Comment: @GensaGames My suggestion is to do this in C++ because it offers a lot of optimization. CUDA/OpenCL, intrinsic functions, compiler optimization etc.

Comment: One huge speedup would be reducing your template matching algorithm time. The dino is only ever in the first portion of the image, never farther than that. So only use `cv2_image[:,:20]` or whatever width value (however far the T-Rex extends) in the template matching portion.

Answer (score 1):

Three big suggestions to help with speed all boil down to the same thing: split different parts of the image for different parts of the processing pipelines. There is an additional speed up that can be gained by looking for different objects. The two goals are to find the dino position, and find the position of new objects in the image.

## Speedup 1

Remove the parts of the image where the T-Rex and the objects don't sit in. By that I mean the top half (ish) of the frame. Objects aren't in here, and that greatly reduces the search space.

## Speedup 2

I mentioned this in the comment on your post. Don't look for the T-Rex throughout the whole frame. You know the T-Rex sticks within some horizontal boundaries in the frame and only moves vertically. Template matching is definitely a slow process so you will get a big speedup by reducing the search area. You could refine this even further by using a smaller template and a smaller search area. Again, you know the T-Rex will be in a certain portion, which means you know the T-Rex *head* or *tail* will be in a certain, smaller region---so search for the head or tail or whatever in that region. You can again refine this even more by reducing the search area to around where it was in the last frame. I did this while [tracking Mario](https://youtu.be/m99H6oH46E8) for example; you can see the white search area box which moves around where Mario's head was in the last frame.

## Speedup 3

Note that you only need to find *new* objects...you know how fast the scrolling is, so you know how fast the objects move once you detect them and where they'll end up in the next frame. Objects aren't the width of the whole frame, they only fill up some percentage of the frame at a time. So in fact you only need to search for new objects as they come in from the right of the screen. Then you can tag them (their width, height, position) and *calculate* their positions after that instead of finding them again each frame. Now, your contour searching only happens in a smaller subset of the frame (faster) and you have less contours to loop through (faster).

## Speedup 4

Note that you can detect cacti simply by the bottoms of them underneath the "ground" line. It seems that similar height cacti have similar width, so if you detect a block say 4 pixels wide, you know the cacti actually extends out 8 pixels beyond that on both sides and is 30 pixels high, or whatever the actual values are. This turns your problem into detecting the base of the cacti instead of the full cacti, and reduces your search area for the cacti immensely. Further, you don't even need to find contours with this approach! You can simply look for blocks in the bottom part of the image and group them together when they're less than some predefined distance apart. This should be *way* faster. And if you do this, you probably don't need to worry about only detecting the objects at the right boundary and then calculate their new positions in new frames...if you're only looking at a 4px wide strip for them, it's probably not much faster than just finding them every frame.

## Other suggestions

I don't really understand the point of blurring and doing adaptive thresholding. The image is already virtually binary; black or non-black pixels. Perhaps this is a way to group together multiple separate objects (like an individual cactus) into a group? Either way there might be better (faster) ways of doing this; for example, if you eroded the image (which expands the dark pixels) then the cacti would merge. I think this would be faster but you'd need to test. If you did this, your contours would then be a bit bigger than their actual width, but you could then compensate by making the bounding boxes smaller by however many pixels you're expanding by. Of course this doesn't matter if you implement speedup 4, but it's something to think about.